# T-SQL count number of different values across multiple columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an SQL database which contains a table with four different currency columns, I need to determine how many different currencies each record has across these four columns, for example..

| Record ID | Curr1 | Curr2 | Curr3 | Curr4 | CurrencyCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GBP | USD | GBP | GBP | 2 |
| 2 | GBP | EUR | GBP | USD | 3 |
| 3 | GBP | GBP | GBP | GBP | 1 |
| 4 | GBP | GBP | GBP | EUR | 2 |

How can I determine the "CurrencyCount" / count of currencies against each record?  I can't think how to approach this

Thank you for any help

Comment: Unpivot and the `COUNT DISTINCT`. If you had a normalised design, this would be much easier.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) referencing columns from the outer row and then `COUNT (DISTINCT` - no need for any expanding out and collapsing with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT *,
       CurrrencyCount = (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Currency) FROM   (VALUES (CURR1), (CURR2), (CURR3), (CURR4)) AS x (Currency))
FROM   YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the work. But not sure how will be the performance if there is a large amount of data.

```
WITH CTE as (
SELECT '1' as RecID,'GBP' as CURR1,'USD' as CURR2,'GBP' as CURR3, 'GBP' as CURR4
UNION ALL
SELECT '2'  ,'GBP'  ,'EUR'  ,'GBP','USD'
UNION ALL
SELECT '3'  ,'GBP'  ,'GBP'  ,'GBP','GBP'
UNION ALL
SELECT '4'  ,'GBP'  ,'GBP'  ,'GBP','EUR'
)

SELECT 
RecID
,CURR1,CURR2,CURR3,CURR4
,COUNT(DISTINCT Currency) as CurrrencyCount
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CURR1), (CURR2), (CURR3), (CURR4)) as x (Currency)
GROUP BY RecID,CURR1,CURR2,CURR3,CURR4
```

Answer (score 0):

Only run this its also work

```
SELECT 
RecordID
,Curr1,Curr2,Curr3,Curr4
,COUNT(DISTINCT Currency) as Currency
FROM  [TABLE_NAME]
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Curr1), (Curr2), (Curr3),(Curr4)) as x (Currency)
GROUP BY RecordID,Curr1,Curr2,Curr3,Curr4
```